# LAN Configuration Form Not Updating /etc/network/interfaces File

Tags: php, html, networking, file-io, interface

Description:
I'm working on a LAN configuration web application where users can update network interface settings using a form. The application appears to run successfully, displaying a "Configuration saved successfully!" message, but the changes made in the form are not reflecting in the /etc/network/interfaces file. I need help diagnosing and resolving this issue.

Issue:
The issue I'm facing is that although the code appears to run successfully and displays the "Configuration saved successfully!" message, the changes made through the form are not updating the /etc/network/interfaces file as expected.

Attempts:
I've already checked the file permissions, and they seem to be set correctly. Additionally, I've verified that the form data is being correctly received by the PHP script. I suspect that the issue might be related to the regular expression pattern used to match the selected interface's section in the file.

Expectations:
I expect that when a user submits the form, the PHP script should update the relevant section in the /etc/network/interfaces file with the new configuration values provided in the form.

Can someone kindly please help me figure out what is wrong with my code.

Code:
I have two main files in my project:

index.html (HTML Form):

```
html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LAN Configuration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>LAN Configuration</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="nm.php">
        <label for="interface">Select Interface:</label>
        <select id="interface" name="interface">
            <option value="eth0">eth0</option>
            <option value="eth1">eth1</option>
        </select><br><br>
    
        <label for="ip_address">IP Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ip_address" name="ip_address" required><br><br>
    
        <label for="gateway">Gateway:</label>
        <input type="text" id="gateway" name="gateway" required><br><br>
    
        <label for="dns_servers">DNS Servers:</label>
        <input type="text" id="dns_servers" name="dns_servers" required><br><br>
    
        <input type="submit" value="Save Configuration">
    </form>       

    <div id="message" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

lanconf.php (PHP Script):

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Retrieve form data
    $selectedInterface = $_POST['interface'];
    $ip = $_POST['ip_address'];
    $gateway = $_POST['gateway'];
    $dns = $_POST['dns_servers'];

    // Read the current contents of the interfaces file
    $filename = '/etc/network/interfaces';
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);

    // Create a regular expression pattern to match the selected interface's section
    $pattern = "/auto $selectedInterface(.*?)iface $selectedInterface/";

    // Create the new configuration for the selected interface
    $newConfig = "auto $selectedInterface\n";
    $newConfig .= "iface $selectedInterface inet static\n";
    $newConfig .= "    address $ip\n";
    $newConfig .= "    gateway $gateway\n";
    $newConfig .= "    dns-nameservers $dns\n";

    // Replace the existing section with the new configuration
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $newConfig, $content);

    // Write the updated content back to the file
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);

    echo "Configuration for $selectedInterface has been updated.";
    echo '<div id="message" style="display: block; color: green;">Configuration saved successfully!</div>';
} else {
    echo "Please fill out the form and submit it.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Most likely you do not have write access to the file in question. Try adding some error handling, check so the file is actually writable `is_writable()` and check the return values of `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` and so on.

Comment: @Cyclonecode Okay sir, I did though try run some commands to changes the file settings..

Comment: IIRC is_writeable only applies a filesystem permissions check - it doesn't valid MAC policies. The right way to capture the behaviour is using the return value of file_put_contents(). And you need to check the return value from file_get_contents() to ensure you'er not running chroot.